# Getting country currency from country name Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am facing problem in getting currency to a particular country based on country name. I am getting country name from my current latitude and longitude but for that country I need currency.

Can someone help me ?
This is my code I am using for country code based on my current location. Also, few solution which I found not supported to API 14 it's only for API 24.

```
private void getCountryName(double latitude, double longitude) {
        Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(HomeScreenGuestActivity.this);
        List<Address> myList = null;
        String country = "";
        try {
            myList = myLocation.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (myList != null)
                country = myList.get(0).getCountryName();
            Currency cc=Currency.getInstance(myList.get(0).getCountryCode());

        } catch (Exception e) {`enter code here`
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: do you need currency code for a particular country?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Currency` from the address's `Country Code` although it's not very accurate:

```
val locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales().first { it.country == address.countryCode }
val currency = Currency.getInstance(locale)
```